# The value of $E[X|XY]$, where $X,Y$ are two independent standard normal variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

$X,Y$ are two independent standard normal variables, calculate the value of $E[X|XY]$
I was told the result is 0 according to the symmetry, but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I am pretty sure you miss out some information.

Comment: To add to the above, $E(X \rvert XY)$ is a random variable. If this is always zero then $E(E(X \rvert XY)) = E(X) = 0$ but $E(X)$ might not be zero.

Comment: yes, rally sorry that I forgot to mention, they are standard normal

Comment: Since $(X, Y)$ and $(-X, -Y)$ are identically distributed,
$$\mathbb E(X \mid X Y = z) =
\mathbb E(-X \mid (-X) (-Y) = z).$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(X,Y)$ is a random vector such that $(-X,-Y)$ has the same law as $(X,Y)$. Each set in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $XY$ are of the form $\{XY\in B\}$, where $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$. Since $X\mathbf 1_{\{XY\in B\}}$ has the same law as $-X\mathbf 1_{\{(-X)(-Y)\in B\}}$ it follows that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[X\mathbf 1_{\{XY\in B\}}  \right]=0.
$$
The independent between $X$ and $Y$ and he fact that $X$ and $Y$ are both symmetric guarantees here that  $(-X,-Y)$ has the same law as $(X,Y)$.